# Receving different data on different connections on AFTER UPDATE event

Tags: php, firebird

I run several parallel processes each with a open connection to the firebirdSQL database. One process will catch a update event posted by firebird:

```
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE TRIGGER CM_ARTIKEL_AU FOR ARTIKEL
ACTIVE AFTER UPDATE
POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  /* Trigger body */
  Insert into CM_ARTIKEL_CHANGES(
     "TYPE",
     ARTNR
  )
  values (
     'UPDATE',
     old.ARTIKELNR
  );  

  POST_EVENT 'UPDATE_ARTICLE';
END^

SET TERM ; ^
```

**Scenario:**

Process **A** catch a `AFTER_UPDATE` event and informs via rabbitMQ Process **B** and **C** about the dataset to check.

Process **B** execute a `select` statement and retrieves the updated data. Everything is fine.

Process **C** execute a `select` statement and retrieves the *OLD* data, before the update was executed!

Any suggestion why?

Comment: Process C uses a transaction with isolation level snapshot that was started before the update was done? You either need to start a new transaction when performing these checks, or make sure you use a read committed transaction (which might have its downsides depending on what your application does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you see old data, you are using a transaction with isolation level snapshot (aka concurrency) that was started before the change in data was committed.

You need to make sure that when process C queries the data in response to the notification, that it ends (commits) the old transaction and starts a new transaction to get the updated data.

The alternative is to use a transaction with isolation level read committed, but this might have its downsides depending on what your application does.

Comment: I had neglected to perform the read operations (as the write operations) with transactions. If it solves my problem, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @TinoRüb In Firebird there is always a transaction necessary, some drivers hide this fact by starting the transaction when it needs it, and if the driver doesn't use auto commit by default, then you could have long-lived transactions which could lead to invisible updates and potentially cause performance problems related to the 'garbage' of old record versions that need to remain for long running transactions.

Comment: The PHP driver seems the transactions not to start automatically when the transactions are not declared. At least these "auto-transactions" are not included in the firebird trace log output (?). With complete transaction management, it is now working as expected! (: A transaction which was caused by the function `ibase_blob_open()` remained open and caused the problems. ty!